# elem.style.background not being picked up in my jest test

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am dynamically setting an HTML element style with JS via the typical method of using

```
element.style.background = ....
```

however, when I come to test this, it doesn't seem to be applied.

This is made even stranger by the fact that using the 'bad practice' of

```
element.setAttribute('style','background: ...')
```

**IS** picked up in the test.

I have no idea why!

**Class**

```
function applyStyles(document) {
    const myEl = document.querySelector('.section-container');

    const topHeight = myEl.getAttribute('top-height');
    const botHeight = myEl.getAttribute('bottom-height');

    const topBGHeight = myEl.getAttribute('top-height') === '50%' 
       ? topHeight 
       : topHeight + 'px';
        
    const bottomBGHeight = myEl.getAttribute('bottom-height') === '50%' 
       ? botHeight 
       : botHeight + 'px';

    const styleToApply = 'linear-gradient(180deg, ' + myEl.getAttribute('bgcolour') + ' ' + topBGHeight + ', ' + myEl.getAttribute('bgbottom-colour') + ' ' + bottomBGHeight + ')';
        
    // This .style.background doesn't appear to work...
    myEl.style.background = styleToApply;

    // This setAttribute DOES work...
    myEl.setAttribute('style', 'background: ' + styleToApply);
}
```

**Test**

```
test("will apply background style", () => { 
   document.body.innerHTML = "
      <div 
        class='section-container' 
        top-height='50%' 
        bottom-height='50%'
        bgcolour='blue' 
        bg-bottom-colour='green'
      />

   // Run code to apply styles
   applyStyles(document);    

   expected = '<div 
      class="section-container" 
      top-height="50%" 
      bottom-height="50%"
      bgcolour="blue" 
      bg-bottom-colour="green" 
      style="background: linear-gradient(180deg, blue 50%, green 50%)"
   />';

   assert.equal(document.body.innerHTML );
});
```

As I have stated before, using the `setAttribute` 'bad practice method, this seems to work fine, however, doing the `elem.style.background` best practise method doesn't seem to apply the style as I expect...

Instead, when doing the `style.background` method, the test sees:

```
<div 
   class="section-container" 
   top-height="50%" 
   bottom-height="50%"
   bgcolour="blue" 
   bg-bottom-colour="green" 
/>
```

The attribute `style="background: linear-gradient(180deg, blue 50%, green 50%)"` is missing as the last entry of the `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the value of a non-existent attribute `bgbottom-colour`.

Change this line:

```
const styleToApply = 'linear-gradient(180deg, ' + myEl.getAttribute('bgcolour') + ' ' + topBGHeight + ', ' + myEl.getAttribute('bgbottom-colour') + ' ' + bottomBGHeight + ')';
```

To this:

```
const styleToApply = 'linear-gradient(180deg, ' + myEl.getAttribute('bgcolour') + ' ' + topBGHeight + ', ' + myEl.getAttribute('bg-bottom-colour') + ' ' + bottomBGHeight + ')';
```

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
const myEl = document.querySelector('.section-container');
const topHeight = myEl.getAttribute('top-height');
const botHeight = myEl.getAttribute('bottom-height');
const topBGHeight = myEl.getAttribute('top-height') === '50%' ? topHeight : topHeight + 'px';
const bottomBGHeight = myEl.getAttribute('bottom-height') === '50%' ? botHeight : botHeight + 'px';
const styleToApply = 'linear-gradient(180deg, ' + myEl.getAttribute('bgcolour') + ' ' + topBGHeight + ', ' + myEl.getAttribute('bg-bottom-colour') + ' ' + bottomBGHeight + ')';

myEl.style.background = styleToApply;
```

```css
.section-container {width: 100%; padding: 2rem;}
```

```html
<div class='section-container' top-height='50%' bottom-height='50%' bgcolour='blue'  bg-bottom-colour='green'></div>
```

The `setAttribute()` approach didn't work either. It just didn't validate your style values unlike the other approach. You could check this by looking at the generated inline style declaration and you will noticed that even though you can see the inline styles, it is not applied to the element because the non-existent variable `bgbottom-colour` returns `null` in your inline style.